# "npm install leaflet-headless" returning error

Tags: node.js, npm, leaflet, npm-install

I'm trying to run the command 'npm install leaflet-headless' so I can use the leaflet map API with Node.js easily. Upon entering this command I receive the following error:

```
    C:\Users\Rocco\Desktop\Node3\kdApp>npm install leaflet-headless

> canvas@1.3.16 install C:\Users\Rocco\Desktop\Node3\kdApp\node_modules\leaflet-headless\node_modules\canvas
> node-gyp rebuild

-
C:\Users\Rocco\Desktop\Node3\kdApp\node_modules\leaflet-headless\node_modules\canvas>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:449:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:404:11
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Rocco\Desktop\Node3\kdApp\node_modules\leaflet-headless\node_modules\canvas
gyp ERR! node -v v4.6.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok

> contextify@0.1.15 install C:\Users\Rocco\Desktop\Node3\kdApp\node_modules\leaflet-headless\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\contextify
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\Rocco\Desktop\Node3\kdApp\node_modules\leaflet-headless\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\contextify>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:449:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:404:11
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Rocco\Desktop\Node3\kdApp\node_modules\leaflet-headless\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\contextify
gyp ERR! node -v v4.6.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "leaflet-headless"
npm ERR! node v4.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! canvas@1.3.16 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the canvas@1.3.16 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the canvas package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs canvas
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     npm owner ls canvas
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Rocco\Desktop\Node3\kdApp\npm-debug.log
```

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Is Python installed and the evironment variable set?

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, I thought both of these would come with the package itself - so I guess I have neither of them, nor do I know how and where to do these actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.` mean that either Python is not installed or the variable to tell node.js where to search for the executeable (python.exe) is not set. So do the following:

1) Install [Python](http://gyp%20ERR!%20stack%20Error:%20Can't%20find%20Python%20executable%20%22python%22,%20you%20can%20set%20the%20PYTHON%20env%20variable.)

2) Set the evironment variable in the cmd `set PYTHON=C:\{Path to your python install folder}\Python.exe` (Default on windows `C:\Python27\python.exe`)

Comment: Thank you! This fixed the current problem. Unfortunately, a new error arose, which I posted in a new question (I probably should have just edited my original but this somehow didn't cross my mind until after, so sorry Stackoverflow!): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40072376/npm-install-leaflet-headless-returning-errors-after-python-installation